# Am I fully vaccinated for traveling to the UK if I recently got a booster dose?

Tags: uk, covid-19, vaccinations

I'm traveling to the UK in less than 14 days. I've had two doses of Sinovac-CoronaVac last year, but I want to get a Pfizer BioNTech  booster dose before traveling.

I know you have to wait 14 days after your second dose before traveling. Will I still be considered fully vaccinated if I get a booster dose without waiting 14 days to travel?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Will I still be considered fully vaccinated if I get a booster dose without waiting 14 days to travel?

Yes, they currently don't care about the booster. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/countries-with-approved-covid-19-vaccination-programmes-and-proof-of-vaccination